# Calculating the b- value in a DKIM string in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, rsa, sha256, dkim

I am trying to calculate the b= string in the DKIM-Signature for a e-mail message. However I am getting no luck with the methodes available.

I have created a RSACryptoServiceProvider and imported a private key using the fromXMLString option.

creating a signature from a hash and verifying it works fine.

```
Dim hashdata As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(headers.ToString)
Dim signature As Byte() = RSA.SignData(hashdata, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"))
If RSA.VerifyData(hashdata, "SHA256", signature) = True Then
    headers.AppendLine("Signature: RSA-SHA256 ")
Else
    headers.AppendLine("Signature: None")
End If
```

The above code verifies the signature, but the DKIM does not pass valid as a whole.

I have seen a example of bouncyCastle "

```
ISigner sig = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA256WithRSAEncryption");
```

But I cant use this in my programming.

Can someone help me on the way on how to properly sign a canonicalized header for dkim purpose ?